# Тетрис с помощью элемента canvas

Tags: javascript

Нужно нарисовать с помощью канваса-тетрис, но дальше начального кода дело не пошло. Помогите.

```js
var c = document.getElementById("c");
var ctx = c.getContext('2d');


ctx.strokeStyle = '#000000';
ctx.strokeRect(18, 18, 260, 450);


ctx.fillStyle = "rgb(255, 0, 0)";
ctx.fillRect(100, 50, 30, 30);

ctx.fillStyle = '#00ff00';
ctx.fill();
```

```html
<canvas height='1200' width='1600' id='c'>FX</canvas>
```

[image: как должно быть]

Comment: Вам весь тетрис написать?

Comment: Эм, хотя бы какую то часть, чтобы понять принцип.

Comment: Вот вы работаете в компании. У вас новый проект, новая игра. Вы что будете каждый раз делать: подходить к директору и скажете: вы можете часть игры на писать, чтобы я принцип понял?

Comment: Так мне не игру нужно написать, а просто визульную часть через канвас без анимаций и всего остального.)

Comment: @Arkrade для этого нужно идти на ютуб

Comment: @Arkrade Возражаете директору/начальнику "ну напишите за меня хотя бы визуальную часть")))

Comment: Какие тут токсичные товарищи, однако. Всем спасибо, все свободны.)

Comment: @Arkrade: токсичность эта против заразы всякой. Например, таких вирусов, как: лень, невежество и хамство.

Answer (score 0):

В играх есть такая штука как игровой цикл. Вам нужно с помощью window.requestAnimationFrame (прошу почитать про эту функцию, или использовать setInterval вместо нее) перерисовивать вашу игры каждый кадр. Все очень удобно так как в функцию отрисовки можно запихнуть всю игровую логику, а сами фигуры представить как объекты с методом draw (ООП и ES6 классы вам в помощь).